# Преждевременный вызов clicked.connect() в PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5

При вызове кода в текущем состоянии выводится окно с двумя кнопками и двумя QLineEdit.

Предполагается, что при отсутствии комментария на строке `#self.dataBrowse.clicked.connect(self.btnDataClicked())` по нажатию верхней кнопки открывается `QFileDialog`, который передает в соответствующий `QLineEdit` имя файла и оттуда уже забирается имя для реализации кода, которого здесь нет.

При раскомментировании `#self.dataBrowse.clicked.connect(self.btnDataClicked())` и запуске кода начинается сразу выполняется соответствующая функция. Почему так происходит?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent=None)

        self.dataEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.sensorEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        self.dataBrowse = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Browse', self)
        #self.dataBrowse.clicked.connect(self.btnDataClicked())

        self.sensorBrowse = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Browse', self)

        self.hbox_main = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        self.vbox_left = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox_left.addWidget(self.dataEdit)
        self.vbox_left.addWidget(self.sensorEdit)

        self.vbox_right = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox_right.addWidget(self.dataBrowse)
        self.vbox_right.addWidget(self.sensorBrowse)

        self.hbox_main.addLayout(self.vbox_left)
        self.hbox_main.addLayout(self.vbox_right)
        self.setLayout(self.hbox_main)


    def btnDataClicked(self):
        fname = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)[0]
        self.dataEdit.setText(fname)

    def btnSensorClicked(self):
        fname = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)[0]
        self.sensorEdit.setText(fname)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle("OOP")
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

P.S. Читал документацию, но так и не понял, можно ли например передавать функции `btnClicked` нужный `QLineEdit`, чтобы не создавать функции `btnDataClicked` и `btnSensorClicked`, которые выполняют одно и тоже действие для разных `QLineEdit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

замените `self.dataBrowse.clicked.connect(self.btnDataClicked())` на `self.dataBrowse.clicked.connect(self.btnDataClicked)`

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent=None)

        self.dataEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.sensorEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        self.dataBrowse = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Browse', self)

#        self.dataBrowse.clicked.connect(self.btnDataClicked())
        self.dataBrowse.clicked.connect(self.btnDataClicked)            # +++

        self.sensorBrowse = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Browse', self)
        self.sensorBrowse.clicked.connect(self.btnSensorClicked)

        self.hbox_main = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        self.vbox_left = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox_left.addWidget(self.dataEdit)
        self.vbox_left.addWidget(self.sensorEdit)

        self.vbox_right = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox_right.addWidget(self.dataBrowse)
        self.vbox_right.addWidget(self.sensorBrowse)

        self.hbox_main.addLayout(self.vbox_left)
        self.hbox_main.addLayout(self.vbox_right)
        self.setLayout(self.hbox_main)


    def btnDataClicked(self):
        fname = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)[0]
        self.dataEdit.setText(fname)

    def btnSensorClicked(self):
        fname = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)[0]
        self.sensorEdit.setText(fname)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle("OOP")
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]